# Login with Google for Flutter app hosted on AWS. Flutter amplify seems too immature

Tags: flutter, google-oauth, aws-amplify

I want to add a login with Google to a Flutter app hosted on AWS. The most obvious solution was to use Flutter Amplify. But I can see the library is still too immature (amplify_flutter: ^0.6.12) and has seen breaking changes, even in minor version updates, especially for iOS.

Is there a better way to implement this, like an open source framework or library. I know it has to pass through API Gateway. But I am looking for a pluggable solution.

Comment: There are too many options to list, since you posted to AWS: AWS ApiGatway and Cognito could be some startpage words for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another package: https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2 - This is quite comprehensive and provides most of the standard functionality we can use until Flutter Amplify is mature and ready for production.